# Join on results of aggregate query in Slick 3.0

Tags: scala, slick

How do you perform a join on the results of an aggregate query in Slick?

I'm currently trying the following, which tries to count the number of uses of an item, and then looks up the details for the 5 most frequent items:

```
val q = itemUses
        .groupBy(_.itemID)
        .map { case (id, uses) => (id, uses.length)}
        .sortBy(_._2.desc).take(5)
val q2 = q.join(items).on(_._1 === _.itemID)
db.run(q2.result).map { result =>
  result.map(r => (r._2, r._1._2))
}
```

The code type checks, but when I run the code, I get the error:

Column "X2.X6" not found; SQL query: select x2.x3, x2.x4, x5."ITEM_ID", ... from (select "ITEM_ID" as x3, count(1) as x4 from "ITEM_USES" group by "ITEM_ID" order by count(1) desc limit 5) x2, "ITEMS" x5 where x2.x6 = x5."ITEM_ID" [42122-191]

[... is above is the data columns from the ITEMS table, excluded for brevity]

I don't know where Slick is getting the x2.x6 identifier from when generating the condition or the join. Looks like it just decided to generate a fresh identifier. Any ideas?